# Mesos Kafka task failed memory limit

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos, mesosphere

I am going to set up a kafka cluster on apache mesos.
I follow the instruction at [kafka-mesos on github](https://github.com/mesos/kafka). I installed a mesos cluster (using [Mesosphere](https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/datacenter/install/) without Marathon) with 3 nodes each with 2 CPUs and 4GB memory. I tested the cluster with hello world examples successfully.

I can run kafka-mesos scheduler on it and can add brokers to it.
But when i want to start the broker, an memory limit issued appear.

```
broker-191-.... TASK_FAILED slave:#c3-S1 reason:REASON_MEMORY_LIMIT
```

Although, the cluster has 12GB memory, but broker just need 3GB memory with 1GB heap. (I test it with various configuration from 512M till 3GB, but not worked)

What is the problem? and what is the solution?

the complete story is here:

```
2015-10-17 17:39:24,748 [Jetty-17] INFO  ly.stealth.mesos.kafka.HttpServer$  - handling - http://192.168.11.191:7000/api/broker/start
2015-10-17 17:39:28,202 [Thread-605] INFO  ly.stealth.mesos.kafka.Scheduler$  - [resourceOffers]
mesos-2#O1160 cpus:2.00 mem:4098.00 disk:9869.00 ports:[31000..32000]
mesos-3#O1161 cpus:2.00 mem:4098.00 disk:9869.00 ports:[31000..32000]
mesos-1#O1162 cpus:2.00 mem:4098.00 disk:9869.00 ports:[31000..32000]
2015-10-17 17:39:28,204 [Thread-605] INFO  ly.stealth.mesos.kafka.Scheduler$  - Starting broker 191: launching task broker-191-0abe9e57-b0fb-4d87-a1b4-529acb111940 by offer mesos-2#O1160
broker-191-0abe9e57-b0fb-4d87-a1b4-529acb111940 slave:#c6-S3 cpus:1.00 mem:3096.00 ports:[31000..31000] data:defaults=broker.id\=191\,log.dirs\=kafka-logs\,port\=31000\,zookeeper.connect\=192.168.11.191:2181\\\,192.168.11.192:2181\\\,192.168.11.193:2181\,host.name\=mesos-2\,log.retention.bytes\=10737418240,broker={"stickiness" : {"period" : "10m"\, "stopTime" : "2015-10-17 13:43:29.278"}\, "id" : "191"\, "mem" : 3096\, "cpus" : 1.0\, "heap" : 1024\, "failover" : {"delay" : "1m"\, "maxDelay" : "10m"}\, "active" : true}
2015-10-17 17:39:28,417 [Thread-606] INFO  ly.stealth.mesos.kafka.Scheduler$  - [statusUpdate] broker-191-0abe9e57-b0fb-4d87-a1b4-529acb111940 TASK_FAILED slave:#c6-S3 reason:REASON_MEMORY_LIMIT
2015-10-17 17:39:28,418 [Thread-606] INFO  ly.stealth.mesos.kafka.Scheduler$  - Broker 191 failed 1, waiting 1m, next start ~ 2015-10-17 17:40:28+03
2015-10-17 17:39:29,202 [Thread-607] INFO  ly.stealth.mesos.kafka.Scheduler$  - [resourceOffers]
```

I found the following in Mesos master log:

```
...validation.cpp:422] Executor broker-191-... for task broker-191-... uses less CPUs (None) than the minimum required (0.01). Please update your executor, as this will be mandatory in future releases.
...validation.cpp:434] Executor broker-191-... for task broker-191-... uses less memory (None) than the minimum required (32MB). Please update your executor, as this will be mandatory in future releases.
```

but i set the CPU and MEM for brokers via broker add (update):

```
broker updated:
id: 191
active: false
state: stopped
resources: cpus:1.00, mem:2048, heap:1024, port:auto
failover: delay:1m, max-delay:10m
stickiness: period:10m, expires:2015-10-19 11:15:53+03
```

Comment: REASON_MEMORY_LIMIT does not necessarily mean task was killed because of OOM. Can you please attach executor's stderr?

Comment: I change the `user=vagrant` in `kafka-mesos.properties` to `user=root` and restart mesos which causes the issue to be resolve.

Answer (score 2):

The executor doesn't get the heap setting just the broker. I opened an issue for this https://github.com/mesos/kafka/issues/137. Please increase the mem until a patch is available.

This hasn't been a problem seen I suspect because the mem gets set as a larger value (the size of your data set you don't want to hit disk from when reading) so there is page cache for max efficiencies http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#maximizingefficiency